# For what kind of project will benefits outweigh the added complexity of Immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, immutability, immutable.js

I have been digging into Immutable.js and I like the idea but I have no use for it for now.

Most of my React Redux apps are not that big and demanding on performance of reflow rerender, and I am already using principles described in Flow pattern. I am even using deepfreeze on Reducers in development.

For what kind of project will benefits outweigh the added complexity?﻿

Comment: scaling: when you bounce around a lot of objects that different routines/users can mutate, it gets more complicated than the boilerplate of immutable.  Really the big pay-off isn't immutable per se, it's not changing data in many places that's the big win; immutable just enforces that well.

Comment: To expand on @dandavis, your question answers itself. Immutability allows you to determine that two states are the same based on simple equality of reference. At scale, when rendering performance becomes key, this gives you the fastest determination of whether or not to re-render a component with an updated state.

Comment: Is your question specifically about the virtues of Immutable.js over `Object.freeze`? If so, it's really just a matter of preference. That library, like most libraries, makes some things easier— like chainable setters/getters that only return a new reference when the state really changes— and some things harder (e.g., having its own APIs for data structures).

Comment: for me, the "insta-diff" is less important than the centralized authority. you can get insta-diff by creating new objects all the time, which works just as well (with a normal "API"), except for busy games where there's a strong need to keep object creation (and thus GC) to a min

Comment: @dandavis Sure, you can optimize "diffing" without immutability, just like you can optimize concurrent mutations without it. Regardless of their relative importance, these are just things made easier by immutability.

Comment: @this-vidor: agreed, just pointing out the ups and downs and options. Aside from games, things that change in complicated ways lend themselves, like a WYSIWYG editor for example.